# why is this programm returning free() invalid pointer?

Tags: c++

why is this program returning errors like free() invalid pointer.....
I tried solving the same on paper for input 4$2*3-3+8/4/(1+1) it should work.
can anyone help me solve this problem?
I have already wasted 2+ hr looking at this program.
I tried commenting on some statements and found that conver function is not working properly.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX=50;

class infix{
private:
    char Stack[MAX];
    char *s,*t;
    int top;
public:
    infix();
    ~infix();
    void setexpr(char *s);
    void push(char c);
    char pop();
    void convert();
    int priority(char c);
    void show();
};
////////////////////////////////
infix::infix(){
top=-1;
}
////////////////////////////////
infix::~infix(){
delete[] s;
delete[] t;
}
////////////////////////////////
void infix::setexpr(char *str){
s=new char[strlen(str)+1];
t=new char[strlen(str)+1];
strcpy(s,str);
//cout<<s;
}
////////////////////////////////
void infix::push(char c){
    if(top==MAX-1)
        cout<<"Stack if full.";
        else
            Stack[++top]=c;
}
////////////////////////////////
char infix::pop(){
if(top==-1){
    cout<<"Stackk is empty";
    return -1;
}
else
    return Stack[top--];
}
////////////////////////////////
void infix::convert(){
while(*s){
    if(*s==' ' || *s=='\t'){
        s++;
        continue;
    }

    if(isdigit(*s) || isalpha(*s)){
        while(isdigit(*s) || isalpha(*s)){
        *t=*s;
        s++;
        t++;
        }
    }
    if(*s=='('){
        push(*s);
        s++;
       }

       char opr;
       if(*s=='*' ||*s=='+' ||*s=='/' ||*s=='%' ||*s=='-' ||*s=='$'){
            int flag=1;
        if(top!=-1){
            opr=pop();
            while(priority(opr)>=priority(*s)){
                *t=opr;
                t++;
                if(top!=-1)
                opr=pop();
                else{
                    break;
                    flag=0;
                    }
            }
            if(flag)
            push(opr);
            push(*s);
        }
        else
            push(*s);
        s++;
       }

       if(*s==')'){
        opr=pop();
        while((opr)!='('){
                *t=opr;
                t++;
                opr=pop();
              }
              s++;
       }
}
while(top!=-1){
    char opr=pop();
    *t=opr;
    t++;
}
*t='\0';
}
////////////////////////////////
int infix::priority(char c){
if(c=='$')
    return 3;
if(c=='*' || c=='/'||c=='%')
    return 2;
else{
    if(c=='+' || c=='-')
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}
}
////////////////////////////////
void infix::show(){
cout<<t<<endl;
}
////////////////////////////////

int main(){
char expr[MAX];
infix q;
cout<<"\nEnter an expression in infix form :";
cin.getline(expr,MAX,'\n');

q.setexpr(expr);
q.convert();

cout<<"\nThe postfix expression is :";
q.show();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag irrelevant languages. Your program is written in C++, therefore you should use only the C++ language tag.

Comment: And why don't you use `std::string` for all your strings?

Comment: doesnt matter....please hlp me with this issue...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you modify the pointers `s` and `t`, which means that they no longer points to the same location returned by `new[]`.

When you use `delete[]` you must use the *exact same* pointer as returned by`new[]`.

Not passing the correct pointer to `delete[]` leads to *undefined behavior*.

As a simple solution, use other temporary variables instead of `s` and `t` directly. As a *proper* solution, use `std::string` and iterators.

Comment: in which line did i changed the address of s and t

Comment: @vishnukumar You have `s++` and `t++` in many places.

Comment: i just changed the value on that address

Comment: but those s++ and t++ are under that particular memory they are not going out of bound

Comment: @vishnukumar:, No, you changed the address. (*s)++ would change the value at that address.

Comment: @vishnukumar No you change where `s` and `t` are pointing. Take a pen and some paper, draw a rectangle on the paper, and divide it into a few squares. Now draw an arrow to the first square, and label the arrow `s`. When you do `s++` erase the arrow and redraw it to the second square. That's what is happening, making you loose the original pointer (there's no arrow to the first square any more).

Comment: ok dear got it ....i have passed end address to delete....thank u